# Why does John interweave the stories of Jesus' questioning and Peter's denial?

Tags: john, literary-criticism

In [John 18](http://esv.to/John18), the author weaves together an account of Peter's denial and a questioning of Jesus before Annas. It's very well done and seems rather more complex from a literary standpoint. But what does John gain by telling the stories this way?

Answer (score 2):

The interweaving of the two narratives provides a comparison between the character of Jesus and that of Peter. This functions in a couple ways:

First, by interweaving the two narratives, John puts into sharp contrast Jesus' ability to withstand questioning and Peter's inability. Peter forsakes the truth when questioned even by a servant girl:

> The other disciple, who was known to the high priest, came back, spoke to the servant girl on duty there and brought Peter in.
>
> “You aren’t one of this man’s disciples too, are you?” she asked Peter.
>
> He replied, “I am not.” (18:16-17)

Meanwhile Jesus is questioned by none other than the high priest:

> Meanwhile, the high priest questioned Jesus about his disciples and his teaching.
>
> “I have spoken openly to the world,” Jesus replied. “I always taught in synagogues or at the temple, where all the Jews come together. I said nothing in secret. Why question me? Ask those who heard me. Surely they know what I said.” (18:19-21)

One recalls the earlier statement in [John 3:21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+3&version=NIV), that "whoever lives by the truth comes into the light, so that it may be seen plainly that what they have done has been done in the sight of God." Jesus is portrayed as one not afraid of his accusers, nor afraid to come into the light. He has always taught in public and he denies nothing. Peter, perhaps afraid after having drawn his sword on the high priest's servant, denies Jesus.

Second, the interweaving of the narratives provides John the opportunity to compare Jesus as the good shepherd with Peter as the hired hand.

> I am the good shepherd. The good shepherd lays down his life for the sheep. The hired hand is not the shepherd and does not own the sheep. So when he sees the wolf coming, he abandons the sheep and runs away. Then the wolf attacks the flock and scatters it. The man runs away because he is a hired hand and cares nothing for the sheep. (10:11-13)

Jesus is seen laying down his life for his disciples in 18:8-9:

> Jesus answered, “I told you that I am he. If you are looking for me, then let these men go.” This happened so that the words he had spoken would be fulfilled: “I have not lost one of those you gave me.”

Meanwhile, Peter's actions are that of the hired hand. While he fights at first, ultimately he flees when the wolf comes. This reading is confirmed by Jesus' threefold admonition to Peter in John 21 to feed and take care of Jesus' sheep, corresponding to Peter's threefold denial here in John 18.

---

*Bible quotations from NIV*

Comment: Good answer.  Do you think it's coincidence that Malchus' name means king or kingdom?  Jesus says in John 18:36, *“My kingdom is not of this world. If it were, my servants would fight to prevent my arrest by the Jewish leaders. But now my kingdom is from another place.”*  But there's a problem with that statement.  Peter has been fighting.  And he attacked a man named kingdom.

Comment: @MatthewMiller That's a good question, so [I asked it](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/4974/33). :)

Comment: :). Well I guess you've given me a question to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

John is a superb story-teller. His narrative here presents a series of cut-scenes, each of which presents Peter as something less than a stellar disciple. These scenes serve to show Peter's lack of fidelity to Jesus, as contrasted with the "other disciple" who openly enters the high priest's courtyard together with Jesus and is not shown as denying him. The superiority of this disciple's faith is depicted again in chapter 20.

- In 18:10 Peter violently attacks the high priest's slave prompting Jesus to reprimand him: “Put your sword away! Shall I not drink the cup the Father has given me?”
- in 18:14 Peter then has to wait outside while "another disciple" (possibly John himself) goes with Jesus into the [former] high priest’s courtyard. Peter is allowed inside only after the "other disciple" intervenes on his behalf.
- In 18:17 Peter denies he is Jesus' disciple, in contrast to the "other disciple" who openly entered the courtyard together with Jesus and makes no such denial.
- In 18:18, while Jesus is inside on trial for his life, Peter is shown in the company of the former high priest's servants, warming himself. The other disciple is not mentioned further.
- The scene then shifts back to Jesus' trial, where he is slapped by one of the officials for not showing proper respect to the former high priest and is sent to Caiaphas, the current high priest.
- In v. 25 the scene shifts back to Peter again. He is "still standing there warming himself." He again denies being a disciple.
- In v. 26 Peter also denies having been the the Garden with Jesus, and is caught lying.

This is a masterful piece of storytelling. What the author gains directly by this technique is a powerful dramatic effect, emphasizing Peter's denial again and again in graphic detail. He also shows Peter to be consistently more concerned about his own comfort, warming himself by the fire, rather than with Jesus' welfare or with bearing testimony to his Lord.

Another thing the author gains is to draw a contrast between Peter an the "other disciple" who enters the courtyard with Jesus while Peter remains outside. This figure appears again in chapter 20, and once again proves Peter's better:

> Peter and the other disciple started for the tomb.  Both were running,
> but the other disciple outran Peter and reached the tomb first. He
> bent over and looked in at the strips of linen lying there but did not
> go in. Then Simon Peter came along behind him and went straight into
> the tomb. He saw the strips of linen lying there, as well as the cloth
> that had been wrapped around Jesus’ head. The cloth was still lying in
> its place, separate from the linen. Finally the other disciple, who
> had reached the tomb first, also went inside. He saw and believed.
> (They still did not understand from Scripture that Jesus had to rise
> from the dead.) Then the disciples went back to where they were
> staying.

Here, the "other disciple" shows greater zeal than Peter by outrunning him to the tomb. He properly defers to Peter by allowing the senior disciple to enter first. We cannot say for certain, but it may be significant that the author states that the other disciple "saw and believed" but says nothing about Peter's belief at this point.

**Conclusion: Besides powerful dramatic effect, what the author gains by telling the story in this way is to show Peter to be far from perfect in his faith and closeness to Jesus. Not only does Peter misunderstand Jesus in 18:10, he denies he is a disciple in three separate scenes while Jesus is on trial. The author also contrasts Peter to the "other disciple" who publicly accompanies Jesus into Annas' courtyard while Peter is invited in later at the other disciple's request. Later, the "other disciple" outruns Peter to the empty tomb and is depicted as both seeing and believing, while Peter is depicted as seeing only.**